# estimation method in GAM model

Tags: regression, estimation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, semiparametric

I created a GAM model with semiparametric with parametric and nonparametric covariates. In the parametric regression model there is an estimation method to determine the value of the beta coefficient. And in the nonparametric regression model there is also an estimation method. I want to ask, so to get each beta coefficient estimate in the GAM model, is it done according to each method or how?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both the linear regression parameters and the spline parameters of a GAM are estimated simultaneously by Penalized Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares. The best reference I know of for understanding the algorithm and how its used in estimating a GAM is Simon Wood's book, "Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction With R"

[Amazon link to the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498728332)

Comment: They're typically estimated using *penalised* IRLS for the smoothness selection.

Comment: D'oh! of course. Edited the answer.

Comment: That's a very helpful answer. Thankyou